# NormSInv VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, which keeps giving me the error "application defined or object defined error. I've actually tried a few variants of the line: WS2.Cells(i, 9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Sheets("sheet2").Range(i, 7).Value) - Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Sheets("Sheet2").Range(i, 8).Value) but each one gives me a different error. Has anyone worked with this function before?

code example:

```
Sub dPrime()
Dim i As Long
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Set WS2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
For i = 2 To Sheets("sheet2").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     WS2.Cells(i, 9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Sheets("sheet2").Range(i,     7).Value) - Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Sheets("Sheet2").Range(i, 8).Value)

Next i
End Sub
```

Data example:

```
 0.583333333    0.5
 0.083333333    0.75
 0.25           0.75
 0.416666667    0.75
 0.083333333    0.833333333
 0.416666667    0.75
 0.25           0.5
 0.416666667    0.833333333
 0.583333333    0.833333333
 0.25           0.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Range` where you should be using `Cells` when you're retrieving the value from Columns 7 and 8.

**Change the code:**

`Sheets("sheet2").Range(i, 7).Value`

**to**

`Sheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 7).Value`

The same goes for `Range(i, 8).Value`. A good technique to debugging an unobvious issue like this is to create individual variables whenever possible to see *exactly* where the problem is and isolate it. Like so:

```
Sub dPrime()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Set WS2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim firstCellVal As String
    Dim secondCellVal As String
    Dim firstNormsResult As Double
    Dim secondNormsResult As Double

    firstCellVal = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 7).Value   'add breakpoint here and start stepping through
    secondCellVal = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 8).Value
    firstNormsResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(firstCellVal)
    secondNormsResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(secondCellVal)

    For i = 2 To Sheets("sheet2").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     WS2.Cells(i, 9) = firstNormsResult - secondNormsResult
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much, and thanks for the debugging tip! works like a charm!

Comment: Glad to help! Best of luck with the rest of your project.